# Lodash filtering over multiple different conditions in an array of objects

Tags: node.js, lodash

I have an array of objects converted from a CSV file and there are a lot of junk values (or values i dont need in the rest of my program).

```
{
  'Mailbox ID': '411042035',
  'First Name': 'Amy',
  'Last Name': 'Doe',
  Extension: '117444',
  Email: 'Amy.Doe@Doe.com',
  'Mobile Phone': '',
  Department: 'Department',
  'Job Title': '',
  Roles: 'Standard (International)',
  'User Groups': '',
  Site: '',
  'Cost Center Code': '',
  'Direct Number (DID)': '(555) 555-7804',
  'Phone Make/Model': '12x f56',
  'Ship to: Street Address - Line 1': '555 Main St',
  'Ship to: Street Address - Line 2': '',
  'Ship to: City': 'Philadelphia',
  'Ship to: State/Province/County': 'PA',
  'Ship to: Postal Code': '19000',
  'Ship to: Country': 'US',
  'Emergency Address': '555 Main St, 5TH FL, PHILADELPHIA, PA, 19000, US',
  'Emergency Response Location': '',
  'Fax Cover Page Address': '',
  'User Language': 'English (U.S.)',
  'Time Zone': '(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)',
  Status: 'Enabled',
  'Assigned Call Queues': ''
}
```

I want to filer an array of objects like this where

- 'First Name' does not contain 'VE. ' and
- 'Department' is not 'Physician' and
- the 'Extension' doesnt start with '73' and
- the 'Email' doesnt end with '.comx' and
- the beginning of the 'Email' is not a string of numbers.

I want to use Lodash to add conditions like this, but im not sure of the syntax or the possibilities. How would i also add conditions to the statement?

this is what I have and it is not working:

```
 let records = await _.filter(RC_file_contents, (line) => {
        let _line = line;
        let data = [];
        if(!_line['First Name'].includes('VE.') && !_line['Department'] == 'Physician' && !_line['Email'].includes('.comx')){
            data.push(line)
        }
        return data
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here. It looks like your combining different methods. The filter method determines whether to keep the item or not by the return value of the callback. If the return value is truthy the item is kept, if it's falsey then it's removed. The main reason it isn't working it you are returning an array `data` on every item. An array is a `truthy` value, therefore no items are being removed.

You can do this without lodash since arrays have .filter already.

_.filter isn't async, so you don't need the `await`

```
let records = RC_file_contents.filter(_line => {
  // Return true or false to keep or remove the item
  return (
    !_line['First Name'].includes('VE.')
    && _line.Department !== 'Physician'
    && !/^73/.test(_line.Extension) // Use regex to test what extension starts with (^)
    && !/\.comx$/.test(_line.Email) // Use regex to test what email ends with ($)
    && !/^\d{3,}/.test(_line.Email) // Email doens't start with 3 or more numbers
  );
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. looks like `RC_file_contents is an object :\ so I get - TypeError: RC_file_contents.filter is not a function

Comment: What are your using to read the csv? I'm guessing the array of objects your trying to filter is in a property, or your using a stream.

Comment: I forgot i was restructuring it with the email as the key, but im going to filter it first like an intelligent person - Thank you for your help! I will mark your response as the answer!